# replace multiple Colors with transparent in an image

Tags: php, image, gd, imagick

i have a rain radar image here with big grey and white parts as backgroound. i need to remove the background ( grey / white ) and make in transparent. but it does not work. i already tried

```
   // replace white
   $rgb = imagecolorexact($im, 255, 255, 255);
   imagecolortransparent($im, $rgb);
   // replace grey
   $rgb = imagecolorexact($im, 189, 189, 189);
   imagecolortransparent($im, $rgb);
```

But this is not working. Its only one part transparent ( either the white one or the grey one ). I cannot remove both colors at the same time.

I really have no idea how images work .. so please if you know a way to achieve what i want please let me know.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you possibly have a layered image file? If so you need to flatten the image first.

Comment: no idea what a layered image is? could you check? https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=dwd:RX-Produkt&styles=&bbox=-523.462,-4658.645,376.538,-3758.645&width=512&height=512&srs=EPSG:1000001&format=image%2Fpng

Comment: Please provide the original image for testing.

Comment: https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=dwd:RX-Produkt&styles=&bbox=-523.462,-4658.645,376.538,-3758.645&width=512&height=512&srs=EPSG:1000001&format=image%2Fpng    open this link for the original image

Comment: _“But this is not working”_ - not surprising at all, considering what [imagecolortransparent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) actually does. As the manual says, _“The transparent color is a property of the image, transparency is not a property of the color.”_ You could “re-color” all of your grey parts to be white first, and then specify white as the transparent color, this way it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make all the grey pixels white. Then make all the white pixels transparent. That's it. Read it again :-)

Refer to [PHP GD documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) to check actual parameters and details.

```
// Load up the original image
$src=imagecreatefrompng('weather.png');

// Ensure image is palettised
if(imageistruecolor($src)){
   imagetruecolortopalette($src);
}

// Find nearest colours to white and grey 189
$whiteindex=imagecolorclosest($src,255,255,255);
$greyindex =imagecolorclosest($src,189,189,189);

// Make all greys white and all nearly whites white, and both transparent
imagecolorset($src,$greyindex,255,255,255,127);
imagecolorset($src,$whiteindex,255,255,255,127);

// Write result 
imagepng($src,"result.png");
```

---

Note that the code you started with, and the code above is using the **GD** library that comes ready-installed with most PHP interpreters. You could, instead, use the **IMagick** library (which is the PHP binding of **ImageMagick**) which is much more comprehensive. Your code would become something like:

```
// Move to a format which supports transparency
$imagick->setimageformat('png');

// Set $color to white first
$imagick->transparentPaintImage($color, $alpha, 10 * \Imagick::getQuantum(),false);

// Set $color to grey first
$imagick->transparentPaintImage($color, $alpha, 10 * \Imagick::getQuantum(),false);
```

Comment: need to set transparency `imagecolortransparent($src, $whiteindex);`

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, you can convert to HCL colorspace and select the C (chroma) saturation-like channel and threshold at 0. This turns all grays/black/white pixels black and all color pixels white. Then put the result into the alpha channel of the original image. This assumes the original image is a flattened image and has no other layers. If not, then flatten the image

```
convert radar.png \( +clone -colorspace HCL -channel 1 -separate -threshold 0 \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

Note channels are numbered starting with 0(red or cyan), 1(green or magenta) and 2(blue or yellow). You can use numbers or name. Imagemagick does not keep track of colors for other colorspace by their colorspace channel names. So here use either 1 or green.

[image]

The resulting image has transparency, but which shows up as white in the above due to the white background color.